# MSVC: Crash when invoking a method directly via the VTable that returns by value (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return, visual-studio-2019, vtable

I'm trying to understand why the following code does not properly work in MSVC under Windows. It calls a VTable method directly which returns by **value**.

```
#include <iostream>

#define RETURN_BY_VALUE 1

struct Value {
  int Secret;
};

class IFoo {
public:
#if RETURN_BY_VALUE
  virtual Value GetValue() = 0;
#else
  virtual int GetValue() = 0;
#endif
};

class Foo : public IFoo {
public:
#if RETURN_BY_VALUE
  virtual Value GetValue() { return Value{42};  }
#else
  virtual int GetValue() { return 42; }
#endif
};

int main() {
  IFoo* f = new Foo;
  void* vtable = (void *)(*(std::intptr_t *)f);
  
#if RETURN_BY_VALUE
  std::cout << f->GetValue().Secret << std::endl;
  
  // The pointer to the GetValue function is at 0 byte offset in the Vtable
  auto method = (Value(*)(IFoo*)) (*(std::intptr_t *)(vtable));  
  std::cout << method(f).Secret << std::endl;
#else
  std::cout << f->GetValue() << std::endl;

  auto method = (int(*)(IFoo*)) (*(std::intptr_t *)(vtable));  
  std::cout << method(f) << std::endl;
#endif
  
  delete f;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
> test.exe
42
1820312
```

If we set `RETURN_BY_VALUE` to `0` everything works as expected.

```
> test.exe
42
42
```

Running the sample in godbolt indicates that gcc and clang do not have this issue https://godbolt.org/z/hn4MxK.

A real world application of this would be hooking [GetAdapterLuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-getadapterluid) in d3d12.

Comment: are you sure that is the correct layout of the visual studio vtable?

Comment: Your example for godbolt seems to be wrong. You always output the default way there.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, that's why it works if you set RETURN_BY_VALUE to 0

Comment: @Secundi Thanks, my bad. Fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/hn4MxK

Comment: when invoking undefined behaviour things often appear to work

Comment: Depending on your settings, at least MS VS 2017 will observe a runtime check issue here in Debug. As Alex Guteniev already mentioned: calling convention is the key here to be sure one behaves standard conform. That's also what the MS-Debugger tells me for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't forget about `__stdcall`. Without `__stdcall`, calling convention for free function and for methods differs more. `GetAdapterLuid` is `__stdcall` I guess.
2. With Windows ABI returned structures are passed as hidded out parameter. It looks like that the order between `this` and the hidden parameter is different in method and free function. You can define your function so that is is really out paramteter.

This seem to work for me, though sure it smells:

```
#include <iostream>

#define RETURN_BY_VALUE 1

struct Value {
    int Secret;
};

class IFoo {
public:
#if RETURN_BY_VALUE
    virtual Value __stdcall GetValue() = 0;
#else
    virtual int __stdcall  GetValue() = 0;
#endif
};

class Foo : public IFoo {
public:
#if RETURN_BY_VALUE
    virtual Value __stdcall GetValue() { return Value{42};  }
#else
    virtual int __stdcall  GetValue() { return 42; }
#endif
};


int main() {
    IFoo* f = new Foo;
    void* vtable = (void *)(*(std::intptr_t *)f);
  
#if RETURN_BY_VALUE
    std::cout << f->GetValue().Secret << std::endl;
  
    // The pointer to the GetValue function is at 0 byte offset in the Vtable
    Value v;
    auto method = (void(__stdcall *)(IFoo*, Value*)) (*(std::intptr_t *)(vtable));  
    std::cout << (method(f, &v), v.Secret) << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << f->GetValue() << std::endl;

    auto method = (int(__stdcall *)(IFoo*)) (*(std::intptr_t *)(vtable));  
    std::cout << method(f) << std::endl;
#endif
  
    delete f;
    return 0;
}
```

---

gcc / clang would return your structure exactly as integer, Unix-like systems have different ABI.

---

The cleanest way to implement hooks is to implement methods as methods. Locate methods in your hook vtable exactly as in target vtable, then you don't need to fake a method using free function.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. For a generic implementation I think we would have to alloca the object to prevent the constructor from being invoked twice.

Comment: Placing (C++11 unrestricted) `union` on stack might be better.